# When shutting down the computer all mechanical hard drives make a strange sound

Tags: hard-drive, shutdown

When shutting down the computer (Kubuntu 23.10), all mechanical hard drives (Seagate IronWolf) make a strange sound and the SMART 192 Power-Off_Retract_Count indicator increases steadily.

When shutting down the second system (Ubuntu Server 22.04), the problem does not occur. To be honest, I just noticed this after installing the second system.

EDIT:
I have just noticed that the problem does not occur when using kernel version 6.5.0-15, the current version 6.5.0-17 must be causing the problem.

---

[Issue when shutting down computer: internal hard drive is not shut down properly](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/mantic/+source/linux/+bug/2053041)

Comment: Your details are unclear?  As these the identical drives that you are using on a dual boot system, Kubuntu 23.10 & Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS, thus your comparison?  If that's the case; Ubuntu Server defaults to an older more stable GA kernel stack (5.15) thus it'll be using older kernel modules than your Kubuntu 23.10 system (6.5) but your issue seems to be related to hardware (*potential failure in the future*) more than minor software difference.

Comment: No system is running from HDD, only from two SSD. 22.04 and 23.10 with 6.5.0-15 does not cause strange sounds and does not change Off_Retract_Count in SMART. Three kernel versions, only one causes the problem, in my case it is a strong subset.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-6.5/+bug/2053041

Comment: It's probably a driver problem. Some ACPI functions doesn't seem to be supported from Kubuntu 23.10. You may check the logs of the shutdown progress of Kubuntu.